Add lat long points in a map
I'm trying to add coordinate points on a map. My code worked with the rgdal package but I can't use it anymore. Now I'm trying to adapt the old code using the sf package.
I'm loading my map through the geobr package:
library(sf)
library(geobr)

brasil <- read_state(year = 2020, showProgress = FALSE)

the coordinate base is as follows:
structure(list(geometry = structure(list(structure(c(-68.75375, 
-10.99904), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-72.72181, 
-7.6002), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-70.34421, 
-8.16137), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-67.19084, 
-10.31946), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-67.8156, 
-9.96015), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-67.81134, 
-9.97451), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-67.74061, 
-10.15484), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-68.49207, 
-10.65385), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-36.65936, 
-9.73472), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-43.34302, 
-22.85825), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-67.81134, 
-9.97451), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-35.673, 
-9.58896), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-35.75334, 
-9.58608), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-35.72666, 
-9.66578), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-36.61828, 
-9.42297), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-36.36252, 
-9.90909), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-50.79231, 
2.04788), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-52.50741, 
-0.82827), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-51.05806, 
0.01289), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-51.06114, 
0.01443), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-51.05496, 
0.03629), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-51.28724, 
-0.12125), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-51.83473, 
3.84354), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-51.1667, 
-0.05409), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-58.44538, 
-3.13875), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-60.62821, 
-3.2936), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-60.02361, 
-3.13371), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-60.04465, 
-3.06856), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-60.04587, 
-3.06695), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-63.15203, 
-4.09908), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-60.02243, 
-3.13368), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-59.9205, 
-3.04288), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-60.07575, 
-2.66348), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-59.99029, 
-3.0361), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-57.71528, 
-3.38232), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-56.75037, 
-2.64711), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-60.02245, 
-2.05228), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-64.71758, 
-3.35678), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.40094, 
-12.14792), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-44.99695, 
-12.11793), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.95337, 
-12.28382), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.95339, 
-12.28289), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-39.03736, 
-14.79573), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.68111, 
-12.88374), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-40.51825, 
-11.17427), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-40.08238, 
-13.83787), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.50352, 
-12.97553), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.21926, 
-9.4469), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-39.09503, 
-16.41395), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.45646, 
-12.97978), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.50448, 
-12.97526), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.45588, 
-12.97658), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.50442, 
-12.96904), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.45543, 
-12.97821), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.50918, 
-12.97297), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.50998, 
-12.96984), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.50165, 
-12.95363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.38748, 
-12.95468), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.51373, 
-12.97563), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.50815, 
-12.97109), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-39.23695, 
-12.98125), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-40.85474, 
-14.84014), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-37.79361, 
-4.57374), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.61548, 
-3.74811), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.62544, 
-3.6907), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-40.67437, 
-5.17525), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-39.40444, 
-7.22868), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.56062, 
-3.76063), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.5606, 
-3.7607), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.50988, 
-3.73173), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.48504, 
-3.78135), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.51884, 
-3.74789), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.48853, 
-3.81179), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-67.81134, 
-9.97451), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-39.40431, 
-7.22809), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.5393, 
-3.72938), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.52942, 
-3.72075), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-34.8789, 
-7.11771), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-34.89251, 
-8.07993), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.56664, 
-3.7257), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.48504, 
-3.78135), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-40.89013, 
-3.91222), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-39.29518, 
-6.36355), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-39.29518, 
-6.364), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-39.58159, 
-3.50291), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-39.32376, 
-7.22104), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-39.31595, 
-7.19864), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.62244, 
-3.78571), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-39.29124, 
-5.20059), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.97016, 
-3.61168), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-40.35442, 
-3.67619), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-40.34867, 
-3.69206), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-40.35047, 
-3.68661), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-38.12839, 
-5.24403), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-48.12242, 
-15.82007), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-48.06386, 
-15.81976), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-47.88667, 
-15.79706), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-47.96205, 
-15.80539), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-47.89843, 
-15.80618), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-47.92221, 
-15.82005), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -72.72181, ymin = -22.85825, 
xmax = -34.8789, ymax = 3.84354), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "SIRGAS 2000", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"SIRGAS 2000\",\n    DATUM[\"Sistema de Referencia Geocentrico para las AmericaS 2000\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"Latin America - Central America and South America - onshore and offshore. Brazil - onshore and offshore.\"],\n        BBOX[-59.87,-122.19,32.72,-25.28]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4674]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(integer(0), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor", names = character(0)), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

I'm trying to generate the map with the points with this code:
ggplot(brasil) +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geom), fill="white") +
  labs(title = "Unidades fixas -  Brasil") +
  geom_sf(data = unidades_lat_long, aes(geometry = geometry), fill = "black") +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, face = "italic", lineheight = 1),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
  theme_nothing(legend = T)

and the result is this
View post on imgur.com
desired result
View post on imgur.com

You tried to add the display of the graph but it seems that it didn't work.
Could you add it so that it is simpler to understand what you want to do?

Would you mind to explain what's the desired output and what's wrong with current plot?

i'm trying to upload the image

It works on my end:
library(sf)
library(geobr)
brasil <- read_state(year = 2020, showProgress = FALSE)

unidades_lat_long <- structure(
  list(
    geometry = structure(
[...]
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(brasil) +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geom), fill="white") +
  labs(title = "Unidades fixas -  Brasil") +
  geom_sf(data = unidades_lat_long, aes(geometry = geometry), fill = "black", shape = 18, size = 3) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, face = "italic", lineheight = 1),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())+
  ggmap::theme_nothing(legend = T)


But I would suggest to use {tmap} package, which is dedicated to drawing maps.


tmap::tm_shape(brasil) +
  tmap::tm_polygons(fill = "white") +
  tmap::tm_shape(unidades_lat_long) +
  tmap::tm_dots(size = 0.6, shape = 18) +
  tmap::tm_title("Unidades fixas -  Brasil", position = tmap::tm_pos_in("right", "TOP"), frame = FALSE)


Created on 2024-11-04 with reprex v2.1.1
